# A necessary and sufficient condition for finite normal subgroups using group actions.

Tags: group-theory

For $H$ a finite subgroup of $G$, the mapping $$H\times H \rightarrow G: (h,h') \mapsto hxh'^{-1}$$ defines an action of $H\times H$ on $G$.

Show that $H \lhd G$ if and only if every orbit of this action contains exactly $|H|$ elements.

Any hints on how where to start proving this? One idea I had in proving (=>) is to define an injective map between $H$ and $H \times H$ (which is also finite) and thus obtain a bijection between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $(k,h)\in H\times H$ define a map from $G$ to $G$ by. 
$\varphi_{k,h}(x)=kxh^{-1}$. Notice that $\varphi_{k,h}(G)$ is the orbit of $(k,h)$ under the action.

If $H\lhd G$ then $kxh^{-1}=(kxk^{-1})kh^{-1}\in H$. If follows that $\text{orb}(k,h)=\varphi_{k,h}(G)\subseteq H$. If $a\in H$ then $a=k(k^{-1}ah)h^{-1}\in \text{orb}(k,h).$ Hence $\text{orb}(k,h)=H$.

For the other direction consider the orbit of $(e_H,e_H)$. Clearly the orbit is $eGe=G$. By the hypothesis $|G|=|H|$ and since $H$ is finite then $G=H$. But the clearly $H\lhd G$.

Comment: Ingenious proof. What prompted you to make such an argument in the first half of the proof? It is stronger than what is asked for: you prove group equality instead of same cardinality.